# mercurial and git, how do they handle a check-in when the file was modified

Tags: git, mercurial

Imagine user#1  modifies `file1`, and user#2 also modifies `file1`. The changes do not require any manually merging.

User#1 has already checked in his changes and pushed them to a central repository. Now user#2 wants to push their changes in.

From what I have heard, Mercurial will force you to update your local copy before you push in the changes.  And because of this, the changeset that you push makes it seems as though you modified the files of user#1 when in fact you didn't.

Is this correct?

Does Git do this differently?

Answer (score 3):

When working with a master repository in Mercurial, you have two options.

The typical workflow is to merge. This means that you commit your changes locally, then you pull the second person's change(s) into your clone, then you merge all of the changes into a merge changeset. You can then push both commits to the master repository.

EDITED as per Martin:

The other workflow is to rebase. There are three options here:

1. Don't actually commit your work. Just pull the other user's changes into your tree, update (which will merge where necessary), then commit and push. Obviously this only works if you have one commit to push at a time.
2. Mercurial queues. This is equivalent to temporarily unapplying your patches, pulling the latest work into your clone, then reapplying your patches and committing. However the patches are not applied intelligently and you may run into merge conflicts.
3. Rebase extension. This is newer, and therefore smarter. For a single changeset it resembles a merge commit, but then it deletes your original commit, leaving the changeset with just the other user's changes as its parent. The rebase extension can even rebase your Mercurial queue for you.

Comment: Ok but if you don't rebase, then when I merge the 2 changes (mine and the updated trunk), then I commit, won't the changeset look like it was ALL my changes when in fact it wasn't?

Comment: @Blankman No, the merge commit will be shown as yours, but the information that someone else made these changes in the first place will still in the history. The initial changeset will still be visible as one parent of the merge changeset.

Comment: @Neil: Good answer. I'll just add that rebasing should be done with (surprise) the rebase extension since that will trigger a full three-way merge. Using MQ for rebasing wont give you the same tool-support since MQ is patch-based and real rebases are merge-based.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for Mercurial, but in Git, merges are handled automatically except when two people modify the same location in the same file.

If that happens, the second person to check in has to merge the changes.  The file will look something like this:

```
<<<<<<<<<<
void SomeMethod()
{
    // do something
}
==========
void SomeMethod()
{
    // do something else
}
>>>>>>>>>>
```

The basic idea is that you, as a human who understands code, figure out how to put the changes together in the two sections, and then delete the marker characters.  I can do that by combining the two, if appropriate:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    // do something
    // do something else
}
```

Or I could just use one if it supersedes the other:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    // do something else
}
```

Then I add the merged file and finish the commit.  Or, if I'm not sure whether the changes make sense, I can do as much testing as I want prior to finishing the commit.

In addition to merging, you can also **rebase**.  This changes the nature of the history, so that rather than you and the other person making simultaneous changes, your history is placed after his.  But while rebasing changes the way the history looks, it doesn't change the fact that if the two of you changed the same part of a file, you'll have to merge the changes together. Rebase (and any other potentially merge-y operation like applying/popping a stash or cherry-picking a commit) will present conflicts in the same way as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for git depends on your settings for `git pull`.

When user #2 goes to push, the push will fail because the shared repo has changed. User #2 will be required to pull before pushing.

By default `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`. However, `git pull` can also be configured to be `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.

`git fetch` updates the local representation of the remote repo. Git maintains this area for you automatically.

In the default mode, using `git merge`, git will merge the changes from the remote repo into to local repo. This makes it appear as if the changes for user #1 occurred **after** the changes for user #2. This may also create a so called merge commit.

In the rebase mode, any local changes to the branch are saved, the branch is updated from the remote representation, then the local changes are replayed on top of the branch. In this way, the changes for user #1 occur **before** the changes to user #2.

All of the information from @Kyralessa is correct concerning merge conflicts. Merge conflicts can occur with merge or with rebase.

### Editorial

We prefer to use `git rebase` with `git pull`. This more correctly represents the history of the remote repo. In this example, user #1 pushed changes to the remote before user #2 and the history should reflect that. `git pull` with rebase also avoids the unfortunate side affect of merge commits.